# IndexError : arrays used as indices must be Integers (or boolean) type

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

## Background

I have 4 Numpy 1 D arrays of length 107952899.
I combine the above 1d as multi D array & Transpose them of order `(107952899, 4)` and stored it data1.
I set column names for my array. `(e.g : data1[:, 0] = Index)`

```
(Like above, 0th col - Index, 1st- Time, 2nd- Speed, 3rd col - Brake)
```

I followed the filter process, like speed > 20 and Brake > 30 by using below command.

```
data1 = data1[(Speed > 20) & (Brake > 30)]
```

Now the `data1 shape changed to (35778, 4)`

## Requirement

I want the top N Values in Brake column with corresponding Index column.

(So i thought of sorting the column using `argsort`)

## What i tried

```
data1 = data1 [data1 [:, Brake].argsort()[::-1][: N]]
```

## Problem Facing

When i execute this i received an `IndexError : arrays used as indices must be Integers (or boolean) type`

## What i have done after my error :

My `dtype of data1 is float`. I though i must change the entire array to int.

But Brake column contains elements like `[30.4,30.8,30.9 .....12.053,60.50]`
I shouldn't change to int, since I want to find the maximum element.

Even i tried to change the `dtype to int using astype`, but problem still exits

## Request

How to rectify the above error,such that my requirement gets fullfil

Comment: You cannot slice `ndarrays` with strings. You will have to use inegers for that, smth like `x [x [:, 1].argsort()[::-1][: 10]]`

Comment: Thank you, now i understood my mistake !!!!@yatu